# Align 3 div while the left and right are only repeat-x and the middle is centered

Tags: html, css

I need to align 3 divs.

- 1 div on left side without size specify, it's only a 1 pixel repeat-x.
- 1 div on middle centered to center.
- 1 div on right side without size specify, it's only a 1 pixel repeat-x

Thank you for your feedback.
What I am asking for, is the possibility to put an image on the middle of a page.
BUT: On the right side and the left side of the image, there are 2 areas that can grow according to the screen resolution.
 
These areas are "1 pixel repeat-x" images.
Please note: **the image on the right side and the left side aren't the same picture!**

Below a picture with a sketch that (I hope) will explain my problem:

[image]
Thanks

Comment: Why is the `.middle` element a child of the `.left` element, is this correct?

Comment: Please sketch out what you are trying to achieve

Comment: If left and right are 1px why do you have 100% rules? You also have two siblings in your DOM with 100% on them. You also have middle as child of left? Please reword this question better.

Answer (score 2):

What do you need the last "right" div for? The center element should be wrapped in a container as such:

```css
    .background: {
      position: relative;
      background-image: (your image);
      background-repeat: repeat-x;
    }
    .middle: {
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 1446px;
      background-image: (another image);
      text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
    <div class='background'>
        <div class='middle'></div>
    </div>
```

You should include some more descriptions as to what you are trying to accomplish. It's a bit blurry.

Comment: The "right" div is important because it's not the same picture.
I have edited my question and added a sketch, so you may understand easiyer my question.